# Best "Advanced DSP" book

Tags: reference-request, books

Let's suppose I have finished studying the first college level DSP textbook and I'm looking for a book, that is the next step beyond:
"Digital Signal Processing: Alan V. Oppenheim"

What's the best next book for "Advanced DSP" that would be best to study if on a self-study course?

(self-study meaning, it has sufficient examples and enough technical depth beyond an introduction textbook.)

Comment: That's the orange book, right.  I think it still has Ronald Schafer as the second author.  Despite the title, I am not sure I would call it "introductory".  The word that comes to my mind is "rigorous".  So it really depends on what you want to do DSP with.  Speech?  Communications?  Control Systems?  Media (audio and/or video)?  Image processing?  I would look for textbooks it those specific areas.

Comment: Yes. i believe so.  Do they have an "advanced dsp" survey textbook that  touches on a little bit on all the applications of DSP?  and is a higher level than Oppenheimer textbook?  Im trying to cover all the bases with the least amount of effort.. :-)

Comment: I just think that [the current O&S](https://www.amazon.com/Discrete-Signal-Processing-Oppenheim-Schafer/dp/9332535035/ref=asc_df_9332535035/) is a little fresher and better than the old orange O&S textbook that first came out in the 1970s.  It's more about a rigorous understanding of the principles, and a little about cepstrum and homomorphic DSP.  but there are always applications for filters and FFT and such, and O&S is, as far as i am concerned, the *"bible"* for principles of DSP.

Comment: [here is a good pdf of Rabiner and Schafer](http://research.iaun.ac.ir/pd/mahmoodian/pdfs/UploadFile_2643.pdf).  might not be legit, but you can't complain about the price.

Comment: thanks for the link...looks like a real page turner.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assuming you have completed Oppenheim's *Discrete-Time Signal Processing* book then the next (advanced) step could be anyone of the followings: (assumes a graduate level *Linear System Theory* background)

- Statistical Digital Signal Processing, Monson Hayes
- Multiresolution Signal Decomposition: Transforms, Subbands,Wavelets, A.Akansu
- Adaptive Filter Theory, Simon Haykin
- Multirate Digital Signal Processing, Rabiner
- Discrete Random Signals and Statistical Signal Processing, C.Therrien
- Fundamentals of Statistical Signal Processing : Estimation Theory, S.M.Kay
- Multirate Systems and Filter Banks, P.P.Vaidyanathan
- Wavelets and Filter Banks, Gilbert Strang
- Multidimensional Digital Signal Processing, Dudgeon

To name just a few...

Comment: I'll add Orfanidis "Applied Optimum SP", Papoulis "Signal Analysis", and my favorite Vitterly "Foundations of SP".

Comment: and Rabiner and Schafer, *"Digital Processing of Speech Signals"* or something like that.  very good introduction to LPC in that.

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson absolutely! yet I deliberately left **applications** (image, audio, video, speech, compression, communication etc) out of scope... so this is the additional *theory* of signal processing; mostly *statistical*, *adaptive*, *multirate* and *wavelets*...

Comment: For Adaptive Filter's I would refer to either book by Ali Sayed rather than Haykin's. I found Sayed's approach much more coherent.
For multirate signal processing, the books by Fleige, and Fredrick J. Harris are a little less intense and more approachable than Vaidyanathan's

Comment: @David Yes Sayed's book is also very nice may be just a read after Haykin or even together... I agree on the Fliege vs Vaidyanathan comparison too. You can add them at the end if you think it would be useful. There are so many books that may appeal for some reasons to some readers...

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the good list above, I can also suggest *"Subband Adaptive Filtering: Theory and Implementation"*, by Woon-Seng Gan, Kong-Aik Lee, Sen M. Kuo.