# Looking for books

Tags: reference-request, books

As a math student interested in signal processing, particularly with wavelets, I am seeking recommendations for introductory books on the topic.

My current knowledge is limited to Fourier transforms covered in a standard calculus course. I would prefer books that include a significant number of practice problems.

Comment: There's a book on wavelets by Strang that is quite good.

Answer (score 2):

You can find some good book suggestions for Wavelets under this [post](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/88109/63398). Also check out this [post](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/88121/resource-recommendations-to-learn-audio-processing/88169#88169) for other DSP subtopics, particularly Audio. And this [post](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/55827/63398) for an even more complete list.

If you are an absolute beginner in DSP then perhaps [Signals and Systems by Alan V. Oppenheim](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0138147574) might be a good start. But given that you already have some knowledge on Fourier theory you can directly jump to one of the best DSP books: [Discrete-Time Signal Processing also by Alan V. Oppenhem](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0131988425).

An slightly more advanced book that might be more suitable for you owing to your Mathematics background is: [Foundations of Signal Processing](https://www.fourierandwavelets.org/FSP_v1.1_2014.pdf).

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest ["A Wavelet Tour of Signal Processing: The Sparse Way"](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0123743702) by Stephane Mallat,
and ["Wavelets and Filter Banks"](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0961408871) by Gilbert Strange and Truong Nguyen.